# Issue with renaming Firebase Storage file in React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm having an issue with renaming a file in Firebase Storage from my React app using the handleSaveName function. Here's my current implementation:

firebase came from App.js as a prop:

```
const ImageList = ({ authUser }) => {
```

jsx

```
const handleSaveName = (ref, newName) => {
  // Verify that the file reference is valid
  ref.getMetadata()
      .then((metadata) => {
          // Verify that the file exists in the bucket
          if (metadata.size > 0) {
              const oldPath = ref.fullPath;
              const newPath = oldPath.replace(ref.name, newName);
              const newRef = firebase.storage().ref(newPath);

              // Copy the current metadata to the new file
              newRef.updateMetadata(metadata)
                  .then(() => {
                      // Move the file to the new reference
                      ref.moveTo(newRef)
                          .then(() => {
                              console.log("File renamed successfully!");
                              setEditingImage(null);
                              setNewName("");
                              setImageUrls((prevState) => {
                                  const updatedUrls = [...prevState];
                                  const index = updatedUrls.findIndex(
                                      (item) => item.ref === ref
                                  );
                                  if (index >= 0) {
                                      updatedUrls[index].name = newName;
                                  }
                                  return updatedUrls;
                              });
                          });
                  });
          } else {
              console.log("File does not exist");
          }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
};
```

This is my return:

```
return (
    <div className="list-group shadow mt-5">
        {imageUrls.map(({ url, ref, name }) => {
            const nameWithoutExtension = name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
            const isEditing = editingImage === ref;
            return (
                <div className="list-group-item" key={ref}>
                    <div className="row align-items-center">
                        <div className="col-5">
                            <img src={url} alt={name} style={{ maxWidth: '400px' }} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-7">
                            <h5 className="mb-1">{isEditing ? (
                                <input type="text" value={newName} onChange={e => setNewName(e.target.value)} />
                            ) : nameWithoutExtension}</h5>
                            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => handleDeleteImage(ref)}>Eliminar</button>
                            {isEditing ? (
                                <button className="btn btn-success ml-2" onClick={() => handleSaveName(ref, newName)}>Guardar</button>
                            ) : (
                                <button className="btn btn-warning ml-2" onClick={() => setEditingImage(ref)}>Editar</button>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
);
```

When I try to rename a file using this function, I get an error message saying "localhost/:1

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/userId'. (storage/unauthorized)"

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to fix it. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it?

---

I have tried using the `handleSaveName` function to rename a file in Firebase Storage within my React app. I expected the function to successfully rename the file and update the imageUrls state with the new name. However, when I run the function, I have checked that the reference to the file is valid and exists in my bucket, and I have also tried using the getDownloadURL() method to verify the file URL, but I am still getting the same error. I am not sure what else to try at this point.

This are my rules from firebase storage:

```
rules_version = '2'; 
service firebase.storage { 
  match /b/{bucket}/o { 
    match /{allPaths=**} { 
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you have that allows access to all files storage is:

```
if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
```

But the `userId` variable you use there is not defined anywhere, so the condition will always be false.

If you want to [allow all logged in users access to all files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#all_authenticated_users) that'd be:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want logged in [users to only have access to their own files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access), you will need to introduce a folder structure, which is then where the `userId` variable comes from:

```
// Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```